# Lavabo e lavandino

Tags: word-choice, difference, single-words

Che differenza c'è tra lavabo e lavandino? Sono per caso intercambiabili queste parole o per caso uno si riferisce al bagno e l'altro alla cucina?

Grazie.

Answer (score 8):

Rispondo perché non ho la reputazione necessaria per commentare. La risposta di abarisone è sicuramente più completa della mia, volevo solo aggiungere un dettaglio (per coloro che imparano l'italiano).

**Lavandino** è usato nella lingua parlata e scritta (moderna) per indicare entrambi senza distinzione.

**Lavabo** è un termine più arcaico (insieme a **lavello**, che è usato raramente) e non lo userei mai nella lingua parlata/scritta moderna, a meno che per ottenere un qualche effetto letterario, o per descrivere un luogo storico (per esempio una chiesa).

Comment: Nella mia famiglia, ma non solo, il lavandino di cucina si chiama sempre *lavello*.

Comment: Interessante. In effetti mi posso immaginare l'uso della parola lavello, ma io non ho praticamente mai usato questa parola (sono veneto).

Comment: Anch'io. :-) In dialetto è *seciaro*. Usiamo anche *lavabo*, per il lavandino del bagno.

Comment: ahah! Da me si dice _secer_.

Answer (score 6):

Ho trovato su [questo forum](https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090115073937AAQ96WD) una risposta esauriente al tuo quesito:

> "***lavabo***" prende il nome da una fase detta di purificazione presente in molte cerimonie religiose che prevede il lavaggio delle
> mani, (dal De Mauro "lavabo": prima della riforma liturgica, cerimonia
> che faceva parte dell’offertorio, durante la quale il sacerdote si
> lavava simbolicamente le mani recitando gli ultimi sette versetti del
> salmo).
>
> Infatti, il sanitario posto nel bagno, per dimensioni e forma non
> appare idoneo al lavaggi di cose così il nome suggerisce il suo
> utilizzo prevalente (il lavaggio delle mani) .
>
> Con ***lavello*** invece si indica in modo più generico una vasca con
> acqua corrente e scarico, in lombardia il termine diventa
> ***lavandino***, tuttavia nei vecchi manuali di architettura troviamo per indicare quello in cucina il termine ***acquaio***, mentre con
> lavabo ci si riferisce alla vaschetta in ceramica del bagno
> principale.
>
> Il termine lavello (o ***lavatoio*** quando la vasca ha maggior
> profondità o ha incorporata una parte inclinata sempre in ceramica)
> sono usati per indicare i sanitari posti nei bagni di servizio e nelle
> lavanderie annessi alle cucine, il termine lavello è anche usato per
> indicare la vaschetta ceramica che veniva collocata nelle camere
> d'albergo prive di bagno in camera.
>
> Oggi con lavabo (a colonna, a bacinella soprapiano, sottopiano, a
> semincasso, etc.) si indica il sanitario posto in bagno, mentre con
> lavello (a 1 vasca, a 2 vasche con o senza gocciolatoio) si definisce
> solo quello utilizzato in cucina
>
> Il corretto termine ***acquaio*** che indicava proprio il bacile con
> acqua corrente dove si lavavano le stoviglie è ormai in disuso.

Riassumendo: il termine generale è ***lavandino*** con cui ci si riferisce di solito a quello della cucina (chiamato anche ***lavello*** ed anticamente ***acquaio***) mentre con ***lavabo*** ci si riferisce a quello del bagno.

Comment: Bisogna aggiungere che nel linguaggio comune _lavabo_ è in disuso a dir poco; non l'ho mai sentito usare da nessun Italiano in tanti anni.

Comment: In Toscana a mio parere e' usatissimo il termine "acquaio" per indicare il lavandino di cucina.